# Security in iPhone applications

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Is there any nice documentation which explains various security concerns for an iPhone application. This includes network security as well data security within the device.

Answer (score 0):

The network security stuff is pretty generic for any internet-connected app. As to data security including thwarting jailbroken devices there's a new book last month called Hacking and Securing iOS Applications which is quite good.